# Trouble with 'extern' Keyword

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, extern, unresolved-external

I have a set of global variables and a method in a cpp file.

```
int a;

int b;

int c;

void DoStuff()
{

}
```

in the header file I have declared them explicitly with the extern keyword. My problem is when I include the header file in another C++ file, I can't use the external variables and the method. It's giving a linker error saying **error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol** for the methods and variables. What have I done wrong here??

PS: DoStuff() method populates the variables. All the header files and cpp files are in the same project folder.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Define those variables inside your header instead of just declaring them.

`extern int x;` is just a declaration(not a definition)

Simple example

`a.cpp`

```
 int a,b,c; //definition

 void doStuff(){ 

 }
```

`b.cpp`

```
extern int a,b,c; //extern keyword is mandatory
void doStuff();   //extern keyword is optional because functions by default have external linkage

int main()
{

   doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must include the **.cpp** file which defines those `extern` variables and the function declared in your header in the compilation set.  If the **.cpp** file containing the definitions is not compiled and linked against one which uses the declarations from your header file, you will get linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're linking in the object file that corresponds to the source file containing your methods and variables?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Visual-C++ (according to the tag), I'd just make sure that all your files are in the same project when compiling. Make sure you are building project and not just building a file.

I doubt this is the case, but you also might want to check that the source files are either compiled as C or as C++, or you might get into some trouble with the naming scheme.